# Regex : expression to match specific word

Tags: regex, informatica

I have a regex replace function:

```
reg_replac​e(Input_Colu​mn,'\b(?:(?!https|www|http)\w)+\b', 'x')
```

With `www.google.com` input, the result is `www.x.x` where as it should be `www.xxxxxx.xxx`.

Please help me to write a regex which works by letters and not by words.

Comment: sometime informatica doesnt work with reg ex formats. so pls let us know if below solution works. you can use simple `REPLACE()` function to replace all chars after http.www.

Comment: I hope my solution was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```php
\w(?!\w*\b(?<=\bhttps|\bwww|\bhttp))
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/hWMXZV/1)

**Explanation**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w                       word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w*                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                               and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      https                    'https'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                               and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      www                      'www'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                               and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      http                     'http'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: thanks @ Ryszar Czech. It perfectly worked. Sorry for late reply.

Comment: another help on same topic......we have req to replace numbers as well in website by 9 example https:\\www.google123.com should be https:\\www.xxxxxx999.xxx

Comment: @PrakharModi There is no way to use one regex for this. Use `[^\W\d_](?![^\W\d_]*\b(?<=\bhttps|\bwww|\bhttp))` to mask letters (https://regex101.com/r/hWMXZV/2) and then replace `\d` with `9` (https://regex101.com/r/hWMXZV/3).

Comment: Just checked quickly...it works fine but for all small or capital letter it does the same.

Comment: But now i am covered. Used the same regex for multiple times......